# Custom appsDefaults NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to setup react-native application but I got stuck doing really basic changes to `AooDekegate.m` file. I have no experience in xCode. I have no idea what am I doing.

I was following this tutorial http://www.proreactnative.com/How-to-Develop-iOS-Apps-on-Linux-Using-React-Native/ . I got stuct doing `Edit AppDelegate.m`.

Could you please help me out?

This is my code:

```
/** * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
*
* This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
* LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
* of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
*/

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{ // ERROR !! Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
   @"host_preference": @"localhost",
   @"port_preference": @"8081",
};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults]; // ERROR !! Expected ']'

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

 NSString *host = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"host_preference"];
 NSString *port = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"port_preference"];

 NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@:%@/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true", host, port];
 jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

 RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                     moduleName:@"AwesomeProject"
                                              initialProperties:nil
                                                  launchOptions:launchOptions];
 rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
 rootViewController.view = rootView;
 self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do initialize a data object outside of a function, which would be fine for certain types.

In this case, I would rather declare the given values as constants or simply in the method that makes use of your variables:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{
   @"host_preference": @"localhost",
   @"port_preference": @"8081",
};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];

// Rest of your code
...
}
```

In addition:

If you do not need these values later on again (I don't know the react native framework in detail). You don't have to use NSUserDefaults for this. (NSUserDefaults are an attempt to persist data for the application).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
    NSString *host = @"localhost";
    NSString *port = @"8081";

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@:%@/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true", host, port];


    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                     moduleName:@"AwesomeProject"
                                              initialProperties:nil
                                                  launchOptions:launchOptions];

    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
     UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
     rootViewController.view = rootView;
     self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot. That looks like it is working. I know that it may seem like a stupid mistake but I have no idea how C or xCode syntax looks like.

Comment: You're Welcome Michal. Glad it helped you.

Comment: @Michal just to add some info, some variables can be declared where you put them, but they need to be `static` or `const`. The specific error `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant` simply says you need to declare **constants** in that place. Your `NSDictionary` is not constant, because the elements inside of it can be modified. But if you declare `static NSString *someString = @"HELLO";` it will work, as that string will not vary in time. The same string instance will be passed all over your different `AppDelegate` instances (just one for this particular class).

Comment: @Michal in other words: The compiler doesn't know, at **compile time**, if your `NSDictionary` will be static or not, but it can know that for `NSString`. That's why you have to declare your dictionary inside of a method, because it will be created and used at **execution time**.